# Copy output of one project to output of other project

Tags: c#, build, post-build-event

I have two C# projects. One is MainProject(exe) and other is ModuleProject (dll). What I want is that when I build my Moudule project, a copy of its output dll is copied to MainProject output folder. If I am building project in debug then it should go to debug folder.

I guess we can achieve this using build events, but I am not familiarized with them. Can anyone tell me exact command what should I write there, or any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) link to learn about the post build:

use `$(OutDir)` to get to the output directory or `$(TargetFileName)` for the dll name. copy it using the copy command like in command line

it should be something like this:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)lib\$(ProjectName).dll"
```

or something like:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll" "d:\\MainProject\\bin\\debug\\$(ProjectName).dll"
```